# Status D when checkout in git

Tags: git, github

when i conduct to checkout branch in Git, i see status D before every file. You can help me explain what that mean ?
You can look at this:
 [image]

Comment: file might got deleted from repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the files have been deleted by a commit in the upstream repo. You can find the meanings of the letters on the [git-status man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).

Answer (score 2):

When you see a letter `x file`in git status. This `x` means something happened in the remote repo. Here are the alternative options and their respective meanings in `git status`.

> ```
> ' ' = unmodified
>
> M = modified
>
> A = added
>
> D = deleted
>
> R = renamed
>
> C = copied
>
> U = updated but unmerged
> ```